# Is it necessary to run SET ANSI_NULLS ON and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS ON every time I do a CREATE/ALTER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I understand what these settings do and why they're important.  However, I have a few questions:

If I run this once before a CREATE/ALTER:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

Is it necessary to run it again the next time I do another CREATE/ALTER?

Basically, are these SET commands making changes that persist across batches/connections?

Answer (score 1):

Any `SET` options specified when an object is created (table or otherwise) are tied to that object in perpetuity, and those settings matter. For instance, to add a filtered index to a table, it must have been created with a whole host of correctly specified `SET` options. You can see all those options by looking in `sys.sql_modules`.

However once the object is created, those options cannot be changed (or at least not by any means I'm aware of), so adding `SET` options to an `ALTER TABLE` script would apply to any SQL you were to run (as usual) but would not update the `SET` options associated with that table.

Comment: This sounds like the right answer.  Any references you can point to to verify this is correct?

Comment: I mostly just ran tests on my machine (at work; dont have the script right now). I created a table with settings I knew woudlon't work for a filtered index, then tried to build one .Surprise, it failed. Then i got the settings right, and recreated the table. Surprise, it worked. Then I ran an alter statement with bad settings and it had noeffect on the filtered index.. I'll see if I can find a few of the actual posts and whatnot I used too though.

Comment: Yeah can't find any seminal article on the subject, but most of the posts I read said there is no way to alter the `SET` options on a table once it's been created. I was able to test to make sure they're not reset during, say, an alter by looking at `sys.modules` and I was able to see that the documentation on `alter table` doesn't surface a way to modify them. All that to say, no, you don't have to set them every time. But remember, if you start a new script and you either do or dont want, say, quotedentifiers usable, you WILL still have to set that anyway.